# Huawei PushKit with Ionic & Capacitor not triggering onRemoteMessageReceived

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated Huawei PushKit with the plugin found here https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-cordova-plugin but I will add the code from the ionic example from the same repo as it behaves in exactly the same way

```
this.hmsPushEvent.onRemoteMessageReceived((result) => {
      this.addLog(
        "REMOTE_DATA_MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
        JSON.stringify(result) + "\n"
      );
      this.hmsLocalNotification.localNotification({
        [this.hmsLocalNotification.Attr.title]: "DataMessage Received",
        [this.hmsLocalNotification.Attr.message]:
          new this.hmsPush.CordovaRemoteMessage(result.msg).getDataOfMap(),
      });
    });
```

this callback never gets called.

I get the token just fine and sending a "Notification message" works, however I was expecting that sending a "Data message" would trigger this callback and it does not. I should note that in logcat I do see the Warning "** onMessageReceived **", so on the native level the message does seem to work it just doesn't make it's way to the angular app.